# TransactionRequiredException with WeblogicJtaTransactionManager

Tags: spring, hibernate, jta, distributed-transactions, weblogic12c

I am trying to work with distributed transactions in my application. For this purpose I have configured WeblogicJtaTransactionManager (provided by spring)to manage my distributed transaction. But its seems transactions are not starting. While running update query the get the following exception :

```
 Executing an update/delete query; nested exception is
 javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
```

My application context  :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.jasypt.org/schema/encryption http://www.jasypt.org/schema/encryption/jasypt-spring31-encryption-1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

<!-- <tx:jta-transaction-manager /> -->
<tx:annotation-driven  transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true"/> 

<context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp">
    <context:exclude-filter type="regex" expression="com.myapp.controllers"/>
</context:component-scan>

   <jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="jdbc/myDataSource" id="dataSource"/>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jtaDataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.myapp.domain" />
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode">NONE</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${app.db.dailect}</prop>
            <prop key="initialSize">${app.db.minpoolsize}</prop>
            <prop key="maxActive">${app.db.maxpoolsize}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">0</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.query.substitutions">true=1, false=0</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">false</prop>
            <prop key="javax.persistence.query.timeout">600000</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.JtaTransactionFactory</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform">org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.WeblogicJtaPlatform</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<!-- <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
    </property>
</bean> -->

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebLogicJtaTransactionManager"  >
    <property name="transactionManagerName" value="javax.transaction.TransactionManager"/>
</bean>
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.myapp.repos" factory-class="com.myapp.repos.BaseRepositoryFactoryBean" 
entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: As Abhijeet suggested I have created data source in weblogic and referred them using jndi. But I am still getting the same error. Have updated the config files

Comment: can u paste ur modified XML?

Comment: Current applicationcontext.xml is the updated one. I have used jee:jndi-lookup tag for jndi lookup

Answer (score 1):

It is the problem with your datasource. You are using ComboPooledDataSource which is not managed by weblogic.

Comment: So what datasource should i use??

Comment: you have to configure a datasource in weblogic and look up using JNDI

Comment: Ain't that a bit too much server container dependent? Isn't there a better way? Also i running weblogic through eclipse ide pluggin. so i am not sure i can configure datasources in weblogic

Comment: Okay. Let me ask you why do you want to use a distributed container managed transaction? You can use very well use  LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean if it is not distributed.

Comment: Its is distributed. Thats y i want to use it. I access two more databases. Currently i have configured only one and trying to make things work. I would need to configure two more databases.

Comment: okay then you have to depend on weblogic to define your datasources. Application server , in this case Weblogic is a container. So you are defining your datasources outside the container using ComboPooledDataSource and asking weblogic to manage your transaction across these data sources! Now the question is how would Weblogoic know about these datasources if you define those outside of the container? Think about it !! The answer is it wont. So as it does not know about the datasources it can not manage the txns!! Make sense?

Comment: Agreed. Makes sense. But I wanted to avoid this. But seems i dont have much of choice. Also could you point me to using jndi names and configuring weblogicjtatransaction manager. Thanks

Comment: I have created data source in weblogic and referred them using jndi. But I am still getting the same error.